# How to use `numpy.savez` in a loop to save multiples numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, save

I want to use `numpy.savez` in a loop to save multiples numpy arrays multiple times, here is an example :

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([5, 6, 12])

for i in range(3):
    np.savez("file_info", info1 = a, info2 = b)
    print('a => ', a)
    print('b => ', b)
    a = a * 3
    b = b * 2
```

The output :

```
a =>  [1 2 3]
b =>  [ 5  6 12]
a =>  [3 6 9]
b =>  [10 12 24]
a =>  [ 9 18 27]
b =>  [20 24 48]
```

But when I read the saved file :

```
npzfile = np.load("file_info.npz")
npzfile['info1']
```

I get only the last array (cuz the content is removed at each loop) :

```
array([ 9, 18, 27])
```

So, my question is, how can I save all the numpy arrays in the same file ?

Comment: By using different output files. Or if you want everything within one file, make one big array of with one more outer-dim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you save a new file of the same name it over-writes the old file. Why don't you take your save out of your for loop:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([5, 6, 12])

save_info = np.zeros([3, 2, 3]) #array to store all the info
#one dimension for each entry in a, one for as many arrays as you have
#generating info, and one for the number of times you'll loop over it

for i in range(3): #therefore i will be [0, 1, 2]
    save_info[:, 0, i] = a #save from the a array
    save_info[:, 1, i] = b #save from the b array
    a = a * 3
    b = b * 2

np.savez("file_info", info1=save_info) #save outside for loop doesn't overwrite
```

I can then read information from the file:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.load("file_info.npz") #load file to data object
>>> data["info1"]
array([[[  1.,   3.,   9.],
        [  5.,  10.,  20.]],

       [[  2.,   6.,  18.],
        [  6.,  12.,  24.]],

       [[  3.,   9.,  27.],
        [ 12.,  24.,  48.]]])
```

Edit:
Or if you're avoiding creating one big array you could rename the file that you're saving to each time you loop through:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([5, 6, 12])

for i in range(3): #therefore i will be [0, 1, 2]
    np.savez("file_info_"+str(i), info1=a, info2=b)
    #will save to "file_info_0.npz" on first run
    #will save to "file_info_1.npz" on second run
    #will save to "file_info_2.npz" on third run

    a = a * 3
    b = b * 2
```

Edit:
You might prefer to make two smaller arrays, one for a and one for b:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([5, 6, 12])

save_a = np.zeros([3, 3]) #array to store all the a runs
save_b = np.zeros([3, 3]) #array to store all the b runs

for i in range(3): #therefore i will be [0, 1, 2]
    save_a[:, i] = a #save from the a array
    save_b[:, i] = b #save from the b array
    a = a * 3
    b = b * 2

np.savez("file_info", info1=save_a, info2=save_b) #save outside for loop doesn't overwrite
```

Comment: I was avoiding to create an array to store all the info because I'm dealing with HUGE data.

Comment: You could save it to different files then? e.g. `np.savez("file_info"+str(i), info1=a, info2=b)`?

Comment: Well, if i do that, i will get .. i don't know maybe 5000 files, I'll see if there is a way around. Thank you.

Comment: Numpy is good at big arrays (I use it to process 5000x3000 colour images all the time) so I wouldn't worry too much unless your data is really **really** huge? Good luck with the project.